# Ways to create stretched canvas view

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, css, image-processing

Here is what I want to achive,

Pure image,

[image]

Created image,

[image]

I have seen lots of apps doing this (http://fineartamerica.com/ is one of them), but I was wondering how it can be done?, what kind of method, algorithm or programming language should I use?

I tried that with css3 bu couldn't get a tangible result, and it won't be a cross browser solution,

-webkit-transform: perspective( 800px ) rotatey( 78deg );

I'm looking for a server side solution.

Comment: What browsers are you looking to support?

Comment: @apaul34208, Actually the most modern browsers, but + ie8 would be great. The actual problem that I couldn't achive is image would be any size, it's not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an app that does what you want but it turns out that there are some problems with the example image you gave. Using your example as a guide, the output of this app looks very close as you can see.

Ex.1) The logic behind formatting the right-side edge is to take the right 10% of the original image and then reflect it around the Y-axis, squash it to 5%, and then warp it. In some cases it looks fine.

[image: Img1]

The problem happens when you use an image like this one:

[image]

The foot gets pulled into the reflected image. A similar problem happens when you gallery wrap a real pre-painted canvas. You either lose the outer border of the painting or you get white sides.

So, after looking at the http://fineartamerica.com link you mentioned, I also included a modified version of what they do there. The difference is that there is a white matte around the image along with the drop shadow like the image below. That way, there are 2 code bases to experiment with.

[image]

Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Ok, so this is quite a bit of code. If you are going to use it server-side in asp.net, wrap it up in it's own dll and reference it. There is some unsafe code and asp.net might bark at you otherwise.

### About the code

- I used a few different pieces that I found on the web and used them to create a usable class. Most importantly, the source from http://www.vcskicks.com/image-distortion.php provided great info on applying quadrilateral distortions to images using GDI+.
- There are magic numbers littered throughout the code because I was mostly interested in recreating your requested result. I just didn't have time to make a totally configurable control.
- The gallery wrap version is MUCH slower that the matted one.
- The `GetCanvasedImage` and `GetMattedImage` functions can be copied or modified to create your own custom image formats.
- The `SHADOW_DEPTH` constant is hard-coded and must be manually adjusted when switching between wrapped or matted output, and/or changing the MAX_LENGTH value. Obviously these could be changed into variables.
- The `MAX_LENGTH` value is used to constrain **either** the width or the height to a maximum value. It just applies it to the longest edge.
- Just copy both classes into a project, a separate namespace, or a separate assembly. Then, pass in a path to an image and get a formatted image as a return value.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public class ImageFormatter {
        public ImageFormatter() {
        }

        private const int MAX_LENGTH = 500;     // Constrain size to the longest edge
        private const int SHADOW_DEPTH = 30;    // This number has to be adjusted to taste 
                                                // for each change in MAX_LENGTH
        private const double PIOver2 = Math.PI / 2.0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a 3D representation of a 2D image, as if stretched around stretcher bars.
        /// </summary>
        public Image GetCanvasedImage(string srcImgPath) {

            Image src = SizeSourceImage(Bitmap.FromFile(srcImgPath));
            Bitmap output = new Bitmap(src, src.Width + (int)(src.Width * .125f), src.Height + (int)(src.Height * .125f));

            using (Bitmap side = new Bitmap((int)(src.Width * .10f), src.Height))
            using (GraphicsPath outline = new GraphicsPath())
            using (Graphics destGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(output)) {

                // Set graphics options
                destGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
                destGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;
                destGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
                destGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                Rectangle shadowRect = new Rectangle(
                    (int)(src.Width * .02),
                    (int)(src.Height * .03),
                    src.Width + (int)(src.Width * .07),
                    src.Height + (int)(src.Height * .03)
                );

                // Counter-clockwise points of front rectangle
                Point[] destPoints = new Point[] { 
                        new Point(0, (int)(src.Height * .02f)), 
                        new Point(src.Width, 0), 
                        new Point(src.Width, src.Height),
                        new Point(0, src.Height - (int)(src.Height * .02f))
                    };

                outline.AddPolygon(destPoints);

                // Draw the drop shadow first
                DrawRectangleDropShadow(
                    destGraphics,
                    shadowRect,
                    Color.FromArgb(25, 25, 25),
                    SHADOW_DEPTH,
                    128
                );

                // Draw front rectangle warped
                destGraphics.DrawImage(ImageFormatter.Distort(
                    (Bitmap)src,
                    destPoints[0],
                    destPoints[1],
                    destPoints[3],
                    destPoints[2],
                    3
                ), 0, 0);

                // Create the inverted right-side graphic
                src.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);

                using (Graphics sideGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(side)) {
                    sideGraphics.DrawImage(
                        src, 
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, side.Width, side.Height),
                        new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(side.Width, side.Height)),
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                destPoints = new Point[] { 
                    new Point(src.Width, 0), 
                    new Point(src.Width + (int)(side.Width * .5f), (int)(side.Height * .03f)), 
                    new Point(src.Width + (int)(side.Width * .5f), src.Height - (int)(side.Height * .03f)), 
                    new Point(src.Width, src.Height)
                };

                // Draw side rectangle warped
                destGraphics.DrawImage(ImageFormatter.Distort(
                    (Bitmap)side,
                    destPoints[0],
                    destPoints[1],
                    destPoints[3],
                    destPoints[2],
                    3
                ), 0, 0);

                outline.AddPolygon(destPoints);

                // Draw outline
                GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate);
                destGraphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, outline);
            }

            return output;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a matted representation of an image with accompanying drop shadow
        /// </summary>
        public Image GetMattedImage(string srcImgPath) {

            Image src = SizeSourceImage(Bitmap.FromFile(srcImgPath));
            int borderWidth = (int)(src.Width * .05f);

            Rectangle imageRect = new Rectangle(
                0, 
                0, 
                src.Width + borderWidth * 2, 
                src.Height + borderWidth * 2
            );

            Rectangle outputRect = new Rectangle(
                0,
                0,
                src.Width + borderWidth * 2 + (int)(src.Height * .10f), 
                src.Height + borderWidth * 2 + (int)(src.Height * .10f)
            );

            Rectangle shadowRect = imageRect;
            shadowRect.Inflate(8, 8);
            shadowRect.Offset(5, 5);

            Bitmap output = new Bitmap(outputRect.Width, outputRect.Height);

            using (GraphicsPath outline = new GraphicsPath())
            using (Graphics destGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(output)) {

                // Set graphics options
                destGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
                destGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;
                destGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed;
                destGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                // Draw shadow
                DrawRectangleDropShadow(
                    destGraphics,
                    shadowRect,
                    Color.FromArgb(25, 25, 25),
                    SHADOW_DEPTH,
                    128
                );

                // Draw image
                destGraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, imageRect);
                destGraphics.DrawImage(src, borderWidth, borderWidth);
                destGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, imageRect);

                // Draw outline
                //destGraphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, outline);
            }

            return output;
        }

        private Image SizeSourceImage(Image src) {
            int newWidth = 0;
            int newHeight = 0;

            if (src.Width >= src.Height) {
                if (src.Width <= MAX_LENGTH)
                    return src;

                double ratio = (double)src.Height / src.Width;
                newWidth = MAX_LENGTH;
                newHeight = (int)(MAX_LENGTH * ratio);
            }
            else {
                if (src.Height <= MAX_LENGTH)
                    return src;

                double ratio = (double)src.Width / src.Height;
                newHeight = MAX_LENGTH;
                newWidth = (int)(MAX_LENGTH * ratio);
            }

            double edgeWidth = newWidth * .05;

            Image resized = new Bitmap(src, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resized);

            return new Bitmap(src, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));
        }

        private struct Vector {
            public PointF Origin;
            public float Direction;

            public Vector(PointF origin, float direction) {
                this.Origin = origin;
                this.Direction = direction;
            }
        }

        public static Bitmap Distort(Bitmap sourceBitmap, PointF topleft, PointF topright, PointF bottomleft, PointF bottomright) {
            return Distort(sourceBitmap, topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright, 2);
        }

        public static Bitmap Distort(Bitmap sourceBitmap, PointF topleft, PointF topright, PointF bottomleft, PointF bottomright, int interpolation = 0) {
            double sourceWidth = sourceBitmap.Width;
            double sourceHeight = sourceBitmap.Height;

            //Find dimensions of new image
            PointF[] pointarray = new PointF[] { topleft, topright, bottomright, bottomleft };

            int width = int.MinValue;
            int height = int.MinValue;

            foreach (PointF p in pointarray) {
                width = (int)Math.Max(width, p.X);
                height = (int)Math.Max(height, p.Y);
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

            //For faster image processing
            FastBitmap newBmp = new FastBitmap(bitmap);
            FastBitmap sourceBmp = new FastBitmap(sourceBitmap);

            newBmp.LockImage();
            sourceBmp.LockImage();

            //Key points
            PointF tl = (PointF)topleft;
            PointF tr = (PointF)topright;
            PointF br = (PointF)bottomright;
            PointF bl = (PointF)bottomleft;

            // sides
            float ab = GetAngle(tl, tr);
            float cd = GetAngle(br, bl);
            float ad = GetAngle(tl, bl);
            float bc = GetAngle(tr, br);

            //Get corner intersections
            PointF o = GetIntersection(new Vector(tr, ab), new Vector(br, cd));
            PointF n = GetIntersection(new Vector(tl, ad), new Vector(tr, bc));

            if (interpolation <= 0) 
                interpolation = 1;

            int middleX = (int)(interpolation / 2.0);

            //Array of surronding pixels used for interpolation
            double[, ,] source = new double[interpolation, interpolation, 4];

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    PointF P = new PointF(x, y);

                    float po = ab; //Default value
                    float pn = bc;

                    if (o != PointF.Empty) //If intersection found, get coefficient
                        po = GetAngle(o, P);

                    if (n != PointF.Empty) //If intersection found, get coefficient
                        pn = GetAngle(n, P);

                    //Get intersections
                    PointF l = GetIntersection(new Vector(P, po), new Vector(tl, ad));
                    if (l == PointF.Empty) 
                        l = tl;

                    PointF m = GetIntersection(new Vector(P, po), new Vector(br, bc));
                    if (m == PointF.Empty)
                        m = br;

                    PointF j = GetIntersection(new Vector(P, pn), new Vector(tr, ab));
                    if (j == PointF.Empty) 
                        j = tr;

                    PointF k = GetIntersection(new Vector(P, pn), new Vector(bl, cd));
                    if (k == PointF.Empty) 
                        k = bl;

                    double jp = GetDistance(j, P);
                    double lp = GetDistance(l, P);
                    double jk = GetDistance(j, k);
                    double lm = GetDistance(l, m);

                    //set direction
                    if (lm < GetDistance(m, P)) 
                        lp = -lp;
                    if (jk < GetDistance(k, P)) 
                        jp = -jp;

                    //interpolation

                    //find the pixels which surround the point
                    double yP0 = sourceHeight * jp / jk;
                    double xP0 = sourceWidth * lp / lm;

                    //top left coordinates of surrounding pixels
                    if (xP0 < 0) 
                        xP0--;
                    if (yP0 < 0) 
                        yP0--;

                    int left = (int)xP0;
                    int top = (int)yP0;

                    if ((left < -1 || left > sourceWidth) && (top < -1 || top > sourceHeight)) 
                        continue;

                    //weights
                    double xFrac = xP0 - (double)left;
                    double xFracRec = 1.0 - xFrac;
                    double yFrac = yP0 - (double)top;
                    double yFracRec = 1.0 - yFrac;

                    //get source pixel colors, or white if out of range (to interpolate into the background color)
                    int x0;
                    int y0;
                    Color color;

                    for (int sx = 0; sx < interpolation; sx++) {
                        for (int sy = 0; sy < interpolation; sy++) {
                            x0 = left + sx;
                            y0 = top + sy;

                            if (x0 > 0 && y0 > 0 &&
                                x0 < sourceWidth && y0 < sourceHeight) {
                                color = sourceBmp.GetPixel(x0, y0);

                                source[sx, sy, 0] = color.R;
                                source[sx, sy, 1] = color.G;
                                source[sx, sy, 2] = color.B;
                                source[sx, sy, 3] = 255.0f;
                            }
                            else {
                                // set full transparency in this case
                                source[sx, sy, 0] = 0;
                                source[sx, sy, 1] = 0;
                                source[sx, sy, 2] = 0;
                                source[sx, sy, 3] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //interpolate on x
                    for (int sy = 0; sy < interpolation; sy++) {
                        //check transparency
                        if (source[middleX, sy, 3] != 0 && source[0, sy, 3] == 0) {
                            //copy colors from 1, sy
                            source[0, sy, 0] = source[1, sy, 0];
                            source[0, sy, 1] = source[1, sy, 1];
                            source[0, sy, 2] = source[1, sy, 2];
                            source[0, sy, 3] = source[1, sy, 3];
                        }
                        else {
                            //compute colors by interpolation
                            source[0, sy, 0] = source[0, sy, 0] * xFracRec + source[middleX, sy, 0] * xFrac;
                            source[0, sy, 1] = source[0, sy, 1] * xFracRec + source[middleX, sy, 1] * xFrac;
                            source[0, sy, 2] = source[0, sy, 2] * xFracRec + source[middleX, sy, 2] * xFrac;
                            source[0, sy, 3] = source[0, sy, 3] * xFracRec + source[middleX, sy, 3] * xFrac;
                        }

                        //interpolate transparency
                        source[0, sy, 3] = source[0, sy, 3] * xFracRec + source[middleX, sy, 3] * xFrac;
                    }

                    //now interpolate on y

                    //check transparency
                    if (source[0, middleX, 3] != 0 && source[0, 0, 3] == 0) {
                        //copy colors from 0, 1
                        source[0, 0, 0] = source[0, middleX, 0];
                        source[0, 0, 1] = source[0, middleX, 1];
                        source[0, 0, 2] = source[0, middleX, 2];
                        source[0, 0, 3] = source[0, middleX, 3];
                    }
                    else {
                        source[0, 0, 0] = source[0, 0, 0] * yFracRec + source[0, middleX, 0] * yFrac;
                        source[0, 0, 1] = source[0, 0, 1] * yFracRec + source[0, middleX, 1] * yFrac;
                        source[0, 0, 2] = source[0, 0, 2] * yFracRec + source[0, middleX, 2] * yFrac;
                        source[0, 0, 3] = source[0, 0, 3] * yFracRec + source[0, middleX, 3] * yFrac;
                    }

                    //interpolate transparency
                    source[0, 0, 3] = source[0, 0, 3] * yFracRec + source[0, middleX, 3] * yFrac;

                    //store to bitmap
                    if (source[0, 0, 3] != 0) //pixel has color
                        newBmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb((int)source[0, 0, 3], (int)source[0, 0, 0], (int)source[0, 0, 1], (int)source[0, 0, 2]));
                }
            }

            sourceBmp.UnlockImage();
            newBmp.UnlockImage();

            return bitmap;
        }

        private static double GetDistance(PointF A, PointF B) {
            float a = A.X - B.X;
            float b = A.Y - B.Y;
            return Math.Sqrt((double)(a * a + b * b));
        }

        private static PointF GetIntersection(Vector vector1, Vector vector2) //Vector[] pointAngularCoeff)
        {
            if (vector1.Origin.X == vector2.Origin.X && vector1.Origin.Y == vector2.Origin.Y)
                return vector1.Origin;

            if (vector1.Direction == vector2.Direction) return PointF.Empty; //Parallel, no intersection

            float newX = float.Epsilon;
            float newY = float.Epsilon;

            if (float.IsInfinity(vector1.Direction)) {
                newX = vector1.Origin.X;
                newY = vector2.Origin.Y + vector2.Direction * (-vector2.Origin.X + vector1.Origin.X);
            }

            if (float.IsInfinity(vector2.Direction)) {
                newX = vector2.Origin.X;
                newY = vector1.Origin.Y + vector1.Direction * (-vector1.Origin.X + vector2.Origin.X);
            }

            if (newX == float.Epsilon) {
                float q1 = vector1.Origin.Y - vector1.Direction * vector1.Origin.X;
                float q2 = vector2.Origin.Y - vector2.Direction * vector2.Origin.X;
                newX = (q1 - q2) / (vector2.Direction - vector1.Direction);
                newY = vector1.Direction * newX + q1;
            }

            if (float.IsInfinity(newX) || float.IsInfinity(newY))
                return PointF.Empty; //no intersection found
            else {
                return new PointF(newX, newY);
            }
        }

        private static float GetAngle(PointF from, PointF to) {
            double angle = GetAngleRad(from, to);
            double t = angle % Math.PI;

            if (Math.Abs(t - PIOver2) < 0.0000001) //t == PIOver2 (avoid loss of precision bug)
            {
                return float.PositiveInfinity;
            }
            else {
                if (Math.Abs(t + PIOver2) < 0.0000001) //t == -PIOver2 (avoid loss of precision bug)
                    return float.NegativeInfinity;
                else
                    return (float)Math.Tan(angle);
            }
        }

        private static double GetAngleRad(PointF from, PointF to) {
            if (to.Y == from.Y) {
                if (from.X > to.X)
                    return Math.PI;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            else if (to.X == from.X) {
                if (to.Y < from.Y)
                    return -PIOver2;
                else
                    return PIOver2;
            }
            else {
                double m = Math.Atan(((to.Y - from.Y) / (to.X - from.X)));

                if (to.X < 0)
                    if (m > 0)
                        return m + PIOver2;
                    else
                        return m - Math.PI;
                else
                    return m;
            }
        }

        private static void DrawRectangleDropShadow(Graphics tg, Rectangle rc, Color shadowColor, int depth, int maxOpacity) {
            //calculate the opacities
            Color darkShadow = Color.FromArgb(maxOpacity, shadowColor);
            Color lightShadow = Color.FromArgb(0, shadowColor);

            //Create a shape for the path gradient brush
            using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath()) 
            using (Bitmap patternbm = new Bitmap(2 * depth, 2 * depth))
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(patternbm)) {
                gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, 2 * depth, 2 * depth);

                //Create the brush that will draw a softshadow circle
                using (PathGradientBrush pgb = new PathGradientBrush(gp)) {
                    pgb.CenterColor = darkShadow;
                    pgb.SurroundColors = new Color[] { lightShadow };
                    g.FillEllipse(pgb, 0, 0, 2 * depth, 2 * depth);


                    SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(maxOpacity, shadowColor));
                    tg.FillRectangle(sb, rc.Left + depth, rc.Top + depth, rc.Width - (2 * depth), rc.Height - (2 * depth));
                    sb.Dispose();

                    //top left corner
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Left, rc.Top, depth, depth), 0, 0, depth, depth, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    //top side
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Left + depth, rc.Top, rc.Width - (2 * depth), depth), depth, 0, 1, depth, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    //top right corner
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Right - depth, rc.Top, depth, depth), depth, 0, depth, depth, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    //right side
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Right - depth, rc.Top + depth, depth, rc.Height - (2 * depth)), depth, depth, depth, 1, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    //bottom left corner
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Right - depth, rc.Bottom - depth, depth, depth), depth, depth, depth, depth, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    //bottom side
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Left + depth, rc.Bottom - depth, rc.Width - (2 * depth), depth), depth, depth, 1, depth, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    //bottom left corner
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Left, rc.Bottom - depth, depth, depth), 0, depth, depth, depth, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    //left side
                    tg.DrawImage(patternbm, new Rectangle(rc.Left, rc.Top + depth, depth, rc.Height - (2 * depth)), 0, depth, depth, 1, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    unsafe public class FastBitmap {
        public FastBitmap(Bitmap inputBitmap) {
            workingBitmap = inputBitmap;
        }

        private int width = 0;
        private Bitmap workingBitmap = null;
        private BitmapData bitmapData = null;
        private Byte* pBase = null;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct PixelData {
            public byte blue;
            public byte green;
            public byte red;
            public byte alpha;

            public override string ToString() {
                return "(" + alpha.ToString() + ", " + red.ToString() + ", " + green.ToString() + ", " + blue.ToString() + ")";
            }
        }

        public void LockImage() {
            //Size
            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, workingBitmap.Size);
            width = (int)(bounds.Width * sizeof(PixelData));

            if (width % 4 != 0)
                width = 4 * (width / 4 + 1);

            //Lock Image
            bitmapData = workingBitmap.LockBits(bounds, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            pBase = (Byte*)bitmapData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        }

        private PixelData* pixelData = null;

        public Color GetPixel(int x, int y) {
            pixelData = (PixelData*)(pBase + y * width + x * sizeof(PixelData));
            return Color.FromArgb(pixelData->alpha, pixelData->red, pixelData->green, pixelData->blue);
        }

        public Color GetPixelNext() {
            pixelData++;
            return Color.FromArgb(pixelData->alpha, pixelData->red, pixelData->green, pixelData->blue);
        }

        public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color) {
            PixelData* data = (PixelData*)(pBase + y * width + x * sizeof(PixelData));
            data->alpha = color.A;
            data->green = color.G;
            data->blue = color.B;
            data->red = color.R;
        }

        public void UnlockImage() {
            workingBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            bitmapData = null;
            pBase = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ImageFormatter formatter = new ImageFormatter();
        Image output = formatter.GetCanvasedImage(
            @"C:\Development\input.jpg"
        );

        output.Save(
            @"C:\Development\output.jpg",
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Good luck! I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reps. FYI. I just looked at this with a fresh pair of eyes and one thing I noticed is that the outline border color of your example isn't black like mine is. That may be the reason why my edges don't always look so crisp. The anti-aliasing options are pretty limited in .net. Take care.

Comment: hi again I've problem, hope you can help me, your solution is great but on every image there is line appeared bottom of the image could you please help me to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Play with the `SHADOW_DEPTH` property once you've set the `MAX_LENGTH`. The idea is to only see the soft edge of the `PathGradientBrush` used to draw the shadow rectangle. Once you get these values right you can make lots of images of the same length.

Comment: I got the point, you have made shadow with a rectangle, when I play with perspective angle, shadow rectangle is still there. So can't I create a shadow polygon like the image, not a rectangle?

Comment: Sure. `destPoints` is the points of the canvas face. Go ahead and use them. It's all just a starting point for whatever you want. Are you unable to get rid of the line by changing SHADOW_DEPTH?

Comment: No, actually it works when angle is not so much, but when I increase angle rectangle shadow doesn't seem good, it would be better if i can make it polygon, http://i.imgur.com/wUp0Vtj.png

Comment: You might be able to get it the way you want by playing with the magic numbers in the `shadowRect` declaration. They just approximate an offset for the shadow. Try shifting it to the right some. But yes, if you go with a sharp angle you'll need to change the shadowing strategy. You can also play with the `PathGradientBrush` that draws the shadow to get different effects.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what your looking for http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-3d-cube-image-gallery/ ?

**EDIT:**

Based on the url above i made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4eBd/3/) that is pretty close to what you have in the image

In order to achieve this unfortunately i had to use 2 images

The HTML markup is kinda easy . 1 container for front side . 1 for right side

```
<div class="cube">
    <div class="cube-face  cube-face-front"></div>
    <div class="cube-face  cube-face-right"></div>
</div>
```

Then inside the CSS some parts are more important

The right side is moved & rotated

```
left: 600px; /* Moved left 100% of image */

outline: 1px solid transparent; /* Used to smoothen edges in Firefox */

transform: rotateY(25deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(25deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-ms-transform: rotateY(25deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

The front side is translated on the Z axis with the same amount that the right side has been rotated

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 25px);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 25px);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 25px);
```

hope this helps

- try to always use all prefixes ( -o-, -moz-, -webkit, -ms-) when writing CSS3 animations (effects)

**EDIT 2:**

Forgot about the shadow . i used a [box-shadow generator](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/) and applied a shadow to each side .

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 8px 17px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 8px 17px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         7px 8px 17px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4eBd/1/)

**EDIT 3:**

fixed to use only 1 image http://jsfiddle.net/S4eBd/3/

what i did was to make use of background position

front side received `background-position:  left top;`

right side received `background-position:  right top;`

make sure that the 'holder' container is smaller then the image with a % greater then the right side

Comment: Actually I don't want it to cube, but yes 3d. It's a nice tutorial. But I've been playing with it for an hour, but I couldn't convert it like streched (see my example image). Do you have an idea, how can I convert it look like my example image, thanks anyway.

Comment: I have used this code but I got mirror effect in image. 
I need gallary wrap effect like canvas 3D frame. so pls help me how can I get this effect from given code.

Ex  http://i.stack.imgur.com/PSDze.jpg